# How mutate data in method computed?

Tags: vue.js, methods, mutated

I'm on Vue 3. I have an onclick method which is supposed to modify the value of my props which is a boolean, I have tried several ways, I manage to enter the computed method, but the value of my props does not change

I register my data

```
data() {
 return {
  showConsommationWindow: false
 }
}
```

then I tried 3 ways to change the value but none of them worked.
The first :

```
<submit-button v-on:click="showConsommationWindow = true" />
```

the 2nd : (alert is executed but the data value don't change)

```
<submit-button v-on:click="showConsommation(true)"/>

  methods: {
    showConsommation(boolValue){
        alert('false')
        this.showConsommationWindow = boolValue;
      }
  }
```

The last :

```
<submit-button v-on:click="showConsommation"/>

  methods: {
    showConsommation(){
      if (!this.showConsommationWindow) {
        alert('false')
        this.showConsommationWindow = true;
        return
      }
      this.showConsommationWindow = false;
    }
  },
```

I really don't understand why my data can't mutate, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If value comes from a props, it means the **parent** distributes a boolean to the **component**. So if you want to change the boolean value, you should probably do:

```js
// in parent

<Component :booleanValue="myBoolean" @changeBooleanValueEvent="changeMyBoolean" />

...

data() {
  return {
    myBoolean: true
  }
}

methods: {
  changeMyBoolean(value) {
    this.myBoolean = value
  }
}

// in component

props: {
  booleanValue: {
    ...
  }
}

methods: {
  showConsommation() {
    this.$emit('changeBooleanValueEvent', false)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did it differently but your answer put me on the track.
I have wrapped my component in a div and I just do my onclick on this div

Comment: No problem @Péah enjoy :)